# How can I prevent `jsx watch` from compiling swap files?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using vim has an editor. JSX compiles the swap/temporary files. How can I avoid that ?

Command line :

```
jsx --extension js --watch src/ build/
```

What I see in stdout :

```
.helloworld.js.swp changed; rebuilding...
["helloworld"]
["helloworld"]
helloworld.js~ changed; rebuilding...
helloworld.js~ changed; rebuilding...
["helloworld"]
["helloworld"]
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: What version of react-tools are you using? I know this was a problem but I think it's been fixed for several releases.

Comment: I have react-tools 0.11.1

Comment: I have react-tools 0.12.2 and am seeing the same issue with vim's .swp files

Comment: Not a solution but a temporary workaround: `:set noswap, :set nobackup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**VIM solution**:

You can set the swap folder to a different folder.

```
 set directory^=$HOME/.vim/swap//
```

**Grunt solution**:

You can use one of the many plugin available to watch and rebuild the your jsx files. These plugins allow you to set which files to use in the build process. For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-react